# Where is the best place to save a iphone game status - a txt file in xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, filepath

Where is the best place to save a iphone game status - a txt file in xcode 4?

1>Is it possible to save/load from :
[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource]

2> I have trying to save to 
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/E0E287A2-D4A0-464A-AD14-430FE4990570/Documents 
But I cannot load it from there, is it the wrong folder in xcode 4 ? I have read somewhere that this is the right folder in xcode3 but not in xcode4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the target locations moved on XCode4, you can change this on XCode Settings. But, you shouldn't need to reference a file with its absolute path. `[NSBundle mainBundle]` should be your base directory and use the miriad of mothods to get different paths in your bundle.

On another note, have you tried `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`? Seems like you could benefit from it if you are not saving too much information.

Comment: whitelionV: thanks for the clarification. But is it appropriate to save it to resource folder the game progress/status ? I thought I should save it to a folder called Document ? where it is in xcode 4 structure ? Also I need to save a txt file as NSUserDefaults is not suitable for a lot data.